# Handling responses with Python bindings for Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

So I have a webpage that has some javascript that gets executed when a link is clicked. This javascript opens a new window and calls some other javascript which requests an xml document which it then parses for a url to pass to a video player. How can I get that xml response using selenium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, unless the xml is posted to the page, you can't.  Long answer, you can use Selenium to do JS injection on the page so that the xml document is replicated to some hidden page element you can expect, or stored to a file locally that you can open.  This is, of course, assuming that the xml document is actually retrieved client side; if this is all serverside, you'll need to integrate with the backend or emulate the call yourself.  Oh, and one last option to explore would be to proxy the browser Selenium is driving, then inspect the traffic for the response containing the xml.  Though more complicated, that actually could be argued to be the best solution, since you aren't modifying the system under test to test it.

Comment: Do you have an example of what the javascript to do that would look like? Thanks!

Comment: It's dependent on the code in the page you are testing.  You  have to somehow inject your functionality into, or override your functionality over, the existing JS method before it is called via the click event.

Comment: So I've did your last option manually before using Charles on Mac but how would I do that programmatically?

Comment: Googling around a bit, you'll want to use something like http://www.warriorhut.org/whatwg/websocket-proxy.py to dynamically create a proxy, then use browser configuration (like profiles in Firefox) to start webdriver pointed at your proxy http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp.